# JSON Extraction in Python.

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, extract

Trying to get specific data through my JSON format and I'm unable to do so. Trying to do it in Python and I want more than 1 thing printed out. Im providing a example code to make it clear. The name of the file is blah

```
{ u'info': { u'more_info': { u'xyz': u'[]',
                           u'xyz': None,
                           u'xyz': 00000,
                           u'description': u'blah blah blah',
                           u'xyz': 0000,
                           u'url':
                           u'xyz': False,
                           u'name': u'BLAH BLAH',
                           u'xyz': 10,
                           u'xyz': 1,
```

I refer to the documentation, but that still fails me.

I tried this

```
for xyz in blah['info']['more_info']:
fs = xyz['name']['description']['url']
```

The error is that: "TypeError: String indices must be integer"

Please help.

Comment: Careful with your indentation. It's not the cause of the error you're seeing, but the line starting `fs = ` should be indented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over a dict yields keys. But since you have a dict, just access the items directly.

```
print blah[u'info'][u'more_info'][u'name']
print blah[u'info'][u'more_info'][u'description']
print blah[u'info'][u'more_info'][u'url']
```

Comment: And to save repeated lookup costs (and typing), you can assign a local with the results of the first two lookups, `more_info = blah[u'info'][u'more_info']` then use the cached value repeatedly, `print more_info[u'name']`, `print more_info['description']`, etc.